# Couldn't load libfoo: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I did everything "right":

1. Created my JNI module with `LOCAL_MODULE := libfoo` in jni/Android.mk
2. Called `System.loadlibrary("libfoo")`
3. Declared the correct signature for the method and even double-checked it with `javah`

but still got an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception with the message:

> Couldn't load libfoo: findLibrary returned null

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently the *loadLibrary* method prepends "lib" automatically so the proper way to load a filename such as "libfoo.so" is by calling `System.loadLibrary("foo")`.

I learned this the hard way, so you wouldn't have to.

Comment: Man, I wish this would rise to the top of the related Google search. Just saved me a couple (more) hours!

Comment: maaan.. thanks a boatload. has this been changed in some ndk version? what's TOTALLY CRAZY is that I had a lib - that needed another lib. and the autoloader couldn't satisfy the dependency because it tried to load with "libdependedfoo".. so had to add a load for "dependedfoo".

Comment: @LassiKinnunen, what you're talking about is unrelated. The reason the dependencies didn't load IS NOT because of some "lib" prefix. In current NDK versions, the loader does NOT resolve dependencies from the app's lib directory and you always have to load them manually. Even the NDK's docs/CPLUSPLUS.html tells you to do so. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34416

Comment: @Ilya OK I might be wrong, but I was pretty sure I saw in the console output the loader trying to load the library it depended on without the lib prefix(which the binary had in the name) so that might have been cause of confusion.

Comment: The above question-answer is about the "lib" prefix which is added in Java code, before the library name ever reaches the native layer (= dlopen of bionic). The Java code simply does "lib" + libName + ".so" and passes this string to dlopen. Then dlopen opens this library and tries to load the dependencies, without adding "lib" or doing any other funny things. (dlopen's trouble loading your deps is -- it's library path doesn't include your-app/lib, so it can never find them on its own)

Comment: Don't forget to clean the project after changing the library name on `System.loadLibrary("foo")`.